# Show inorder traversal of binary tree

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to make a list showing the inorder traversal of a binary tree.
Here is my code:

```
 (define btree 
 '(1 (2 (4 (7 #f #f) #f) (5 #f #f)) (3 (6 (8 #f #f) (9 #f #f)) #f)))

(define res '())

(define (inorder tree)
  (let loop ([t tree])
    (cond (t (loop (cadr t)) (cons (car t) res) (loop (caddr t)))
      (else res))))

(inorder btree '())
res
```

The returned list is '() and I don't know why.
If I write

```
    (cond (t (loop (cadr t)) (printf "~s " (car t)) (loop (caddr t)))
```

it prints the right result.
Edit: visit was actually res.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work (what is `visit`? `inorder` only takes one argument), you should really be more careful when posting questions on SO. Also, you should include an example call and the desired result.

Nevertheless you were pretty close. You main problem is that you made `res` a global variable, and global variables *rarely* play well with recursion. Also, and probably for that reason, returning `res` is not properly managed. Assuming the result `display`ed by your second implementation is correct, this is the correct code:

```
(define (inorder tree)
  (let loop ((t tree) (res '()))
    (if t
        (loop (cadr t) (cons (car t) (loop (caddr t) res)))
        res)))
```

As you can see

- first we execute `(loop (caddr t) res)`
- using the result of this call as the new `res`, we execute `(cons (car t) <new-res>)`
- and finally, again using the previous result as the new `res` we do `(loop (cadr t) <even newer res>)`

Of course, if `t` is false we just return `res` for the previous logic to work.

I took the liberty of using `if` instead of `cond` but of course `cond` would have worked just as well.

Testing:

```
> (inorder '(1 (2 (4 (7 #f #f) #f) (5 #f #f)) (3 (6 (8 #f #f) (9 #f #f)) #f)))
'(7 4 2 5 1 8 6 9 3)
```